# How to get all of data from API for each page

Tags: api, backend

I did laravel RESTful app, and now I'm creating frontend with vue.js. But I dont understand this part:

If pages on the frontend requests products, categories and main information (like phone, email etc), this should be provided in different requests to the API? In this example, it will be separate request for products `/api/products/get`, categories `/api/categories/get` and like this? Or should I separate data for pages on backend and my API will return all of needed data with `/api/get/mainpage`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, imho best practice will be to use endpoints related to data (e.g. `/api/products/get`).

It will ease your life because in this case you will need to write API once. And then just combine needed endpoints in requests for your frontend pages.

So if you will have to change your frontend, you won't need to change the backend.
Both parts become as independent as possible.